# Given $\varphi$ is golden ratio, how do I prove this $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-\varphi)^j}{j^2}\cos{\frac{3j\pi}{5}}=\frac{\pi^2}{100}$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, summation, irrational-numbers

Given $  \varphi$ is golden ratio, how do I prove this:
$ \displaystyle \tag*{}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-\varphi)^j}{j^2}\cos{\frac{3j\pi}{5}}=\frac{\pi^2}{100}$

My approach:

We can reduce the sum into simpler parts by using the property of golden ratio, we have:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0  \Leftrightarrow 1- \phi = - \dfrac{1}{\phi}$

And I also found the values of $\cos \dfrac{3j\pi}{5}$ in terms of $\varphi$:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \begin{align} \cos \dfrac{3\pi}{5} &= \dfrac{-1}{2 \varphi} \\\\ \cos \dfrac{6\pi}{5} &= \dfrac{-\varphi}{2} \\\\ \cos \dfrac{9\pi}{5} &= \dfrac{\varphi}{2} \\\\ \cos \dfrac{12\pi}{5} &= \dfrac{1}{2 \varphi} \\\\ \cos \dfrac{15\pi}{5} &= {-1} \end{align}$

And this repeats, periodically with alternate opposite signs. I don't know how to connect these information I found to prove the question. Maybe my approach is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since a factor of it is periodic, can you group the sum into periods, and try to calculate the sum for each period?

Comment: [I use i,ndex $k$ where you use $i$ in order to avoid confusions]. This result $\Re(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{((1-\varphi)e^{3i \pi/5})^n}{n^2}=\pi^2/100$ is hopefully connected with the function defined by the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n^2} $ which is the dilogarithm (or Spence) function $Li_2$. See this high level paper https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-30308-4_1/fulltext.pdf where the golden ratio is present many times...

Comment: Explanation : $\cos \alpha$ is the real part of $e^{i \alpha}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is the functional equation $$Li_2(1-z)+Li_2(1-1/z)=-\frac12 \log^2 z$$
of the dilogarithm $$Li_2(z)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k^2}$$ which follows from $z \, Li_2'(z)=-\log(1-z)$,

and that $$1-z= (1-\varphi)e^{3i\pi/5} \implies z=e^{i\pi/5}$$

So $$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(1-\varphi)^k}{k^2}\cos{\frac{3k\pi}{5}}=\frac{-1}4 \log^2 e^{i\pi/5} = \frac{\pi^2}{100}$$

Comment: $\varphi = 1-e^{ 3i\pi/5}-e^{-3i\pi/5}$

Comment: Proceed with what?

Comment: Of course I apply the first formula to $z=e^{i\pi /5}$, so that $1-1/z$ is the complex conjugate of $1-z$.

Comment: @MathLover: the relations give you that your series is $$\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li_2}(1-e^{i\pi/5}) =\frac12\bigl(\operatorname{Li_2}(1-e^{i\pi/5})+\operatorname{Li_2}(1-e^{-i\pi/5})\bigr)=-\frac14\log^2e^{i\pi/5}=-\frac14\,\Bigl[\frac{i\pi}5\Bigr]^2=\frac{\pi^2}{100}.$$

Comment: [+1] I had guessed that $Li_2$ was involved but I hadn't found my way in the jungle of formulas connected with this function.

Comment: Because they are equal. Differentiate both sides and you'll see they have equal derivatives, and they also agree at $z=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For $x \in \mathbb R$
$$\cos x =\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Now let $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}.$$

We have $f(0)=0$ and $$f^\prime(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}=-\frac{1}{x}\ln(1-x)$$

Comment: In fact $f(x)$ is the dilogarithm.